# NSJSONserialisation giving nil due to html errors

Tags: html, objective-c, rest, null, nsjsonserialization

How to ignore any HTML errors from an API response and just consider the success JSON? Actually the response has some errors due to which when I do the JSONSerialisation it always gives me a nil value. I know the API should be rectified, but is there a way to ignore these errors at the app end? This is the API response I am getting:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: Messages</p>
<p>Filename: models/model_ws.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1783</p>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: resendPass</p>
<p>Filename: models/model_ws.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 2021</p>
</div>

{"success":1,"lang":[{"languages":"Spanish","Email_Address":"Correo electronico","Password":"Contrase\u00f1a","ForgoturP":"Olvido su contrase\u00f1a?","New_User":"Nuevo usuario?",
"Sign_IN":"Iniciar sesion","Sign_Up":"Registracion","FName":"Nombre","accountNotCreatedMsg":"Cuenta no fue creada, favor intentar mas tarde...","Last_Name":"Apellido","Email":"Correo electronico","CPassword":"Confirmar contrase\u00f1a","Next":"Siguiente",
"By_Signing":"Al registrarme, yo acepto los terminos","Terms_Services":"Terminos de servicios","and":"y",
"Privacy_Policy":"Politica de privacidad","Security":"Pregunta de seguridad","Answer":"Respuesta",
"Country":"Pais","Mobile_Number":" Numero Movil","Gender":"Sexo","Birthday":"Fecha de nacimiento (DD\/MM)","Anniversary":"Aniversario (DD\/MM)","Cancel":"Cancelar",
"Digit_Number":"Numero de tarjeta virtual","Passcode":"Codigo","Uncheck":"Desactivar la casilla si no quiere recibir  notificaciones push.","Physical":"Desea tarjeta fisica?","Address":"Direccion",
"City":"Ciudad","State":"Estado","Zip":"Codigo Postal","Save_your_Details":"Guardar su informacion","Merchant":"Comerciante","CardNum":"Numero de tarjeta terminado en","Nick_Name":"Apodo",
"LoyaltyP":"Programa de Lealtad","Points":"Puntos","Visits":"Visitas","Rebates":"Reembolsos","Balance":"Balance","Pay_Accure":"Pagar\/Acumular”,…………]}
```

Comment: fix the errors, ignoring them doesn't feel right. if the PHP code belongs to you, read about: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php you can tell the PHP to not write errors directly to STDOUT or at all

Comment: If it's always like this just throw away the part of the string before the first `{` and work from there?

Comment: I recommend too to fix the issue on the server. But in the meantime to get it work, read the result as a `NSString`, and remove the HTML (there are questions on SO about that, hoping that you won't have any HTML in the JSON), then convert it back to `NSData` (you might need to trim for whitespaces and new lines before) and use `NSJSONSerialization`. That's a solution to keep working while the other developer on server fix the issue. It's hacky, not a viable solution for release.